# How do I connect to router "panel" using C#

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, router, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to connect to my router "panel" (192.168.1.1) using a simple C# HTTP Web Request:

```
var userName = "admin";
var passWord = "admin";
var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
var postData = "" + userName;
postData += (":" + passWord); //I saw (using Wireshark) that the HTTP packet is sending the username & password in this form: "username:password"
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.1");
myRequest.Method = "POST"; **//Or should I use GET?**
myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
var newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
newStream.Close();
try
{
  var response = myRequest.GetResponse();
  var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
  var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
  var result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
}
catch (WebException we)
{
  Console.WriteLine(we.Message);
}
```

When I'm running this code I get an saying '**401** Not Authorized Exception', although the UN and Password are correct.

Can anyone suggest me, what's wrong here?

Comment: What type (i.e. make and model) of router are you connecting to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using this as the address and dropping the post data part of your code :

```
http://username:password@192.168.1.1
```

Else, you could use basic authentication, as explained [in this article](http://grahamrhay.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/making-a-post-request-in-c-with-basic-authentication/)

Comment: I tried this:
`var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://admin:admin@192.168.2.1");`
`myRequest.Method = "POST";`
`myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`

            `var response = myRequest.GetResponse();`
           `var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();`
           `var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);`
           `var result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();`

but I still get an 401 Unauthorized Exception

Comment: i'm not sure you've got to POST this as you're doing, I think you should use basic authentication : http://grahamrhay.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/making-a-post-request-in-c-with-basic-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

try this before get respond

```
myRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName,passWord);
```